# My rails app does not display the map using gem geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps-markers, geocoder

The gem by itself is working pretty well because when I register a new location I just put the address and it brings me the latitude and longitude. However, when I try to display this location in a map it does not show anything 
Help please

```
Show.html.erb
<%= image_tag "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=450x300&sensor=false&zoom=16&markers=#{@location.latitude}%2C#{@location.longitude}" %>

location.rb

class Location < ApplicationRecord
geocoded_by :address
after_validation :geocode
end
```

Comment: You have to pay them (Google). I'd be easier to tell if you were handling errors that come from the external request instead of just passing in a hardcoded image_tag string

Comment: Is there a way to use this gem without use google api?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are making a request to Google Maps Platform's [Maps Static API] (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro) without an API key. To use the service, a [key parameter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide#key-and-signature-parameters) is required.

To create a successful request, Google Maps Platform APIs [require](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide#before-you-begin) authentication requirement (which is an API key) and a valid billing account linked to your own Google Maps Platform project.